# Select direct child OR direct child of direct child

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to writ a DRY CSS Selector.

The selector should match elements within a group, but not elements within a group that is a child of the given group.

Elements can only appear as direct children of a given group, or they are wrapped in an extra element.

For the given DOM the standard selector would be: `.grp.A > .el, .grp.A > * > .el`

This can be made DRYer by using: `:is(.grp.A, .grp.A > *) * .el`

For me the DRYest solution would be something like this: `.grp.A:is(*, * > *) > .el`. But it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this selector further?

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".grp.A > .el, .grp.A > * > .el")]);
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(":is(.grp.A, .grp.A > *) > .el")]);
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".grp.A:is(*, * > *) > .el")]);
```

```html
<div class="grp A">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="grp B">
      <div class="el noooooo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="el yes1"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="el yes2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A better title might be something like "Compound selection within matches any pseudo class doesn't work as intended"

Comment: Could be, but I would never have searched for something remotely like your suggested title. Although your suggestion may fit my question, it is not what I intended with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to CSS selectors, I would prioritize readability over being concise. The first selector you show is the most readable

`.grp.A > .el, .grp.A > * > .el`

As for your third attempt, to quote the [CSS Level 4 spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#matches):

> Default namespace declarations do not affect the compound selector representing the subject of any selector within a :is() pseudo-class, unless that compound selector contains an explicit universal selector or type selector.

Had to read this many times, but my understanding is that `:is()` is global scope and the selectors in it can't be compounded based on what's beforehand.

I've added an additional example where a compounding selector within :is doesn't work based off what's beforehand.

```js
// Direct child .el of .grp.A or direct child .el of any direct child of .grp.A
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".grp.A > .el, .grp.A > * > .el")]);
// Direct child .el of .grp.A or direct child .el of any direct child of .grp.A
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(":is(.grp.A, .grp.A > *) > .el")]);
// Direct child .el of .grp.A that is any element, or
// that is any element that's a direct child of any element
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".grp.A:is(*, * > *) > .el")]);
//.grp.A satisfies criteria of being anything, all equating to .grp.A > .el

// Additional example that compounds don't work for :is()
// Only .A of the two arguments in the :is list works
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".grp:is(.A, .A > *) > .el")]);
```

```html
<div class="grp A">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="grp B">
      <div class="el noooooo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="el yes1"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="el yes2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course my example is simplified. In reality the selectors for `.grp.A` and `.el` are more complex and nested. At this point one short but complex selector is more readable than two long comma separated selectors. (Selectors are generated from a DOM Tree to create a page model for e2e tests)

Comment: @htho Had no idea your scenario was more complex than what you provided in the question. I don't think you can get more concise than your 2nd iteration. If you want my help please provide more information on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks @Zach Jensz for now I'll settle with your answer and see how far I can come